# Moq testing repositories

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Trying to moq a repository call.

```
public async Task<T> GetFirstOrDefault<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    return await WithQuery<T, T>(q => q.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate));
}
```

Then in my unit testing:

```
var ruleList = new List<Rule>() (Imagine my list here)

_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetFirstOrDefault<Rule>(x => It.IsAny<string>() == It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(ruleList);
```

This always returns null when it goes into my code.  I have a similar call not using a predicate that will return the value, it looks like this:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAll<T>() where T : class
{
    return WithQuery<T, IEnumerable<T>>(async q => await q.ToListAsync());
}
```

and

```
var ruleList = new List<Rule>() (Imagine my list here)

_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.ListAll<Rule>()).ReturnsAsync(ruleList);
```

This is not null. I'm probably missing something simple at this point but I have tried a few things without luck.

**Edit:** thanks to Nkosi for the explanation and with a slight modification I was able to do:

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetFirstOrDefault<Rule>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Rule, bool>>>()))
    .Returns((Expression<Func<Rule, bool>> predicate) => {
        return Task.FromResult<Rule>(ruleList);
    });
```

Comment: The expression in the setup predicate is trying to use `It.IsAny` a parameter in the expression. That is why it is failing. I am even surprised what you showed would even compile since the example should return a single item and you try to return a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the setup predicate is trying to use `It.IsAny` as a parameter in the expression. That is why it is failing.

If the goal is to try to replicate the expected behavior using the list as a data source then review the following setup example

```
_mockRepository
    .Setup(_ => _.GetFirstOrDefault<Rule>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Rule, bool>>>()))
    .Returns((Expression<Func<Rule, bool>> predicate) => {
        Rule result = ruleList.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        return Task.FromResult<Rule>(result);
    });
```

The expression argument is captured and applied to the list using LINQ